# How to join 2 lists in Angular firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I spent the last 2 hours searching for a solution, and oddly enough, didn't find any. I have worked with sql and nosql databases before but never encountered such a problem. My problem is simple and clear. I have 2 collections : Raw materials & Raw materials stock.
Each raw material stock document contains a raw material key. what i want is to the raw material data by its key and join it to the raw material stock list. For eg
Raw materials Stock document looks like this

```
{
    "factoryKey": "34",
    "quantity": "34",
    //  i want to get this raw material key data such as name...etc
    "rawMaterialKey": "-NDNPe47CDTbjmwGgW_3"
}
```

Raw material document looks like the following

```
{
    "key": "-NDNPe47CDTbjmwGgW_3"
    "code": "R34",
    "name": "RAW2001"
}
```

here's my angular code

```
import {Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {LocalStoreService} from '../local-store.service';
import {AngularFirestore} from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { RawMaterialStock } from '../../interfaces/raw-materials/raw-materiels-stock';
import {AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RawMaterialsStockService implements OnInit {

  rawMaterialsStocksRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  rawMaterialsRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  rawMaterialStockRef: AngularFireObject<any>;

  private dbPathStock = '/raw_material_stock';
  private dbPathRawMaterials = '/raw_material';

  constructor(
    private store: LocalStoreService,
    private router: Router,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase
  ) {

    this.rawMaterialsStocksRef = db.list(this.dbPathStock);
    this.rawMaterialsRef = db.list(this.dbPathRawMaterials);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  // Methods
  getRawMaterialStockList() {
    return this.rawMaterialsStocksRef.snapshotChanges(['child_added'])
      .subscribe(actions => {
        // WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE ????
      });
  }
}
```

Please help me out i' stuck with that problem. i didn't understand any article solving that problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `snapshotChanges` on AngularFire are `Observables`, you can take advantage of [rxjs](https://rxjs.dev/) to help combine them into 1. You will need to combine both the snapshotChanges of `rawMaterialsStockref` and `rawMaterialsRef`.

Here's the steps:

1. Query the `raw material_stock` collection.
2. Once the stock is received, query a `raw_material` document based on the `rawMaterialKey` field
3. Combine it with the `raw_material_stock` into an object.
4. Finally emit the object as an Observable stream

Sample code:

```
this.rawMaterialsStockref =
      firestore.collection<any>('raw_material_stock');
    this.rawMaterialsRef = firestore.collection<any>('raw_material');

    this.rawMaterialsStockref
      .snapshotChanges(['added'])
      .pipe(
        switchMap((stockSnapshots) => {
          const stockWithRawMaterialsObservables = stockSnapshots.map((s) => {
            const stockId = s.payload.doc.id;
            const stock = s.payload.doc.data();

            return this.rawMaterialsRef
              .doc(stock.rawMaterialKey)
              .snapshotChanges()
              .pipe(
                map((rawMaterialSnapshot) => {
                  const rawMaterial = rawMaterialSnapshot.payload.data() ?? {};

                  return { ...rawMaterial, ...stock };
                })
              );
          });

          return combineLatest(stockWithRawMaterialsObservables);
        })
      )
      .subscribe((stocks) => {
        stocks.forEach((s) => console.log(s));
      });
```

Comment: Thank you very much Buddy !!!!! it worked perfectly with just some slight changes since i'm using Realtime database instead of firestore. THANK YOU AGAIN <3